# Ember dependencies "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fitText is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm attempting to use a jQuery plugin (in this case 'fitText') in an Ember project.

In the `ember-cli-build.js` (*that replaced the Brocofile recently...*) - I import the dependency (which I have already installed with bower).

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });

  app.import('bower_components/fittext/fittext.js');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

In my console, I can type in 'fitText' and I DO get the object back. So, it's global now, and I should be able to use it anywhere. BUT `"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fitText is not a function"`

@Tom Netzband pointed out that the bower version of fitText was the one that @adacio maintains and is vanilla JS. I've since switched it out for a `app.import('vendor/jquery.fittext.js');` (*the JS is really only 20 lines or so*)

Previously I needed to import it in the controller or route where I want to use it - but the docs don't reference that anymore. In the docs with `moment.js` as the example, it seems to become a global.

I've put it in the ready hook in app.js - next to similar jQuery things that work fine... but no luck. In this case I only want to affect a few words on the index.hbs / route

### UPDATE

This has really just become another question now. I thought it was still the same problem but it's not. So awarding answer and asking a new one. Thanks.

Comment: It's better to show code that produces error.

Comment: @Artych - added where it's called.

Comment: Can you show us your `bower` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `bower install fittext` doesn't install the jQuery plugin version of fitText, it only installs the plain js version of it.

If you look at your `bower_components/fittext/fittext.js` file, you'll see jQuery isn't passed in or used, and the example from the `example.html` file shows usage as being:

`fitText(document.getElementById('fittext'), 1.2)`

So if you want the jQuery version you might have to download it straight from github and throw it in your `vendor` folder and include it outside of bower.

**UPDATE**

Looks like the version registered with bower is a forked version from the jQuery version where jQuery has been removed: https://github.com/adactio/FitText.js

Comment: AH HA! - I added `app.import('vendor/jquery.fittext.js');` - and tossed the jQuery version in the root of `vendor` ... working things out...

Comment: I'll build a twiddle because something is still not registering.

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a Bower version of the jQuery version of the library.

`bower install FitText.js --save`

Answer (score 0):

I think Dave Rupert has a jQuery version in his crates as well.

```
$ bower install jquery-fittext --save
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work -
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.